# Operand type clash when temp table could have multiple types

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, if-statement

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 that takes an int parameter, @Type int.

Based on the @Type parameter value, it does different processing in building a temp table, #Temp.  If @Type = 0, my ID column contains an int value; if @Type = 1, my ID column contains a uniqueidentifier.

In the stored procedure, I selectively insert into a table:

```
IF @Type = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (IntID)
    SELECT ID
    FROM #Temp
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT ID 
    FROM #Temp
END
```

The IntID column in dbo.MyTable is an int column.  When I call the stored procedure with @Type = 1, I get the following error:

```
Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int
```

Is there any way to avoid this error, besides changing my int column in dbo.MyTable to something else (varchar)?

Comment: Can you help explain why, when `@Type = 1`, that you want to store a `uniqueidentifier` into an `int` column?

Comment: @GordonLinoff It is a uniqueidentifier by default (from the table that I am grabbing it from and putting it into the temp table).  When Type = 0, I handle it differently so that I have a int value - shorter text to handle since size is a limitation when Type = 0

Comment: Use different table/variable names for the different cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly `CAST` the ID field as an Int

```
IF @Type = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (IntID)
    SELECT CAST(ID AS INT)
    FROM #Temp
```

Comment: With that change, I get 'Explicit conversion from data type uniqueidentifier to int is not allowed.'

Comment: I'm not sure I want to ask this, but why would you ever put a uniqueidentifier in a Temp table?

Comment: It is collecting information from another table in the database, stored as a uniqueidentifier.  If the Type parameter is 0, it replaces this field with an int value.

Comment: "it replaces this field with an int value." Where should it get the int value that replaces it? There is no way to convert a  uniqueidentifier to an int (you can't go from 128 bit to 32 bit).

Comment: I didn't notice the  uniqueidentifier in your OP, so this answer is invalid.

Comment: Additional logic is used when building the temp table.  The end result is that when Type = 0 it will have an int value, when Type = 1 it will have a uniqueidentifier.